# attribute is missing the android namespace prefix

Tags: android, xml

Im creating an android app which uses a menu.xml file in the res folder. But I'm getting the above error. What does it mean? How can I fix it?

**menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item id="@+id/my_location"
android:icon="@drawable/my_location"
android:title:="Current location" />

<item id="@+id/mapview_satellite"
android:icon="@drawable/satelliteview"
android:title="Satellite View" />

<item id="@+id/mapview_normal"
android:icon="@drawable/normalview"
android:title="Normal view" />
</menu>
```

Comment: if you get right answer please upvote

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change `<item id="@+id/my_location"` to `<item android:id="@+id/my_location"`. This in all three places.

Also, in here: `android:title:="Current location"` remove the colon after `title`.

Answer (score 11):

You also need to make sure the following two lines are in your attributes list:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

If you omit those, Eclipse will just give you the "missing android prefix" error.

Answer (score 6):

Believe it or not, for anyone who tries to work through examples in downloaded books, you may need to make sure you have true quotation marks as the compiler understands them.  I'd been getting the same error as the OP, and many similar parse errors as I tried to modify an XML  file in small ways.  I noticed then that quote marks from the pasted code snippets were different from the ones on my keyboard (in the snippets they leaned to the right, and if I typed them myself they were straight up and down).

I know this sounds nuts and I could hardly believe it myself, but when I retyped my quotes it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Adding **android:** before the attribute solved my problem.

Comment: worked for me, had to change `<stroke android:width="1dp"  color="#A00080FF"/>` to `<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#A00080FF"/>`

Answer (score 1):

create an XML file inside your project's `res/menu/` directory Not in in `res` folder 
&

dont forget to prefix the id attributes.

**Try like this**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/my_location"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_location"
        android:title="Current location" />

    <item android:id="@+id/mapview_satellite"
        android:icon="@drawable/satelliteview"
        android:title="Satellite View" />

    <item android:id="@+id/mapview_normal"
        android:icon="@drawable/normalview"
        android:title="Normal view" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times the XML code might be written correctly so you need to simply cut what you currently have and then delete it from the line numbers then re-paste it and the error should be fixed. If it doesn't then you know your code is wrong. The xml default is to recognize what you have put at first and needs to be removed in order to begin again. Trust me I just spent 3 days on that very problem and did exactly what is said above, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
        <variable  name="person" type="com.abc.PersonEntity"/>
    </data>
```

Move your data inside layout tag:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
       <data>
          <variable  name="person" type="com.abc.PersonEntity"/>
       </data>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to prefix the `id` attributes. Try to do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/my_location"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_location"
        android:title="Current location" />

    <item android:id="@+id/mapview_satellite"
        android:icon="@drawable/satelliteview"
        android:title="Satellite View" />

    <item android:id="@+id/mapview_normal"
        android:icon="@drawable/normalview"
        android:title="Normal view" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

there was two error silly error

```
- id isn't it attribute is android:id
- First itme android:title:= you have written extra colon after title
```

here is implemented code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_location"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_location"
        android:title="Current location"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapview_satellite"
        android:icon="@drawable/satelliteview"
        android:title="Satellite View"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapview_normal"
        android:icon="@drawable/normalview"
        android:title="Normal view"/>

</menu>
```